# delete files recursively in windows

Tags: windows, file, delete-file

I have a folder. Inside that folder, there are many sub-directories.
In each sub-directory, I have different kinds of files.

I want to delete all the files with `.WAV` extension. I also have `.WAV.wav` files there which I don't want to delete.

I tried `del` but it deletes both the `*WAV` and `*.WAV.wav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well: a `.wav.wav` file **is** as `.wav` file, so isn't that obvious behaviour?
I would advise you to rename your `.wav.wav` files into `.wav.whatever` files, delete the `.wav` files and rename your `.wav.whatever` files back into `.wav.wav` files.

Comment: No, they are not the same, they are different format files, I was looking for a single command to do that easily, where I can specify the extension in a case sensitive way, as far as renaming goes, if that's needed I guess I can write a short python script easily.

Comment: The only way I see left is the usage of `forfiles`. On Reddit, I've found something which checks filename, but it's based on "filename LIKE ..." while you are looking for "filename NOT LIKE ...". I have no idea how to do this. Hereby the Reddit link: https://www.reddit.com/r/Batch/comments/35q7q8/how_do_i_exclude_certain_files_with_windows/

Comment: Thanks, it could be useful. Let me test.